# Server side URL Encoding

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets

How can we Sanitize, via URL/HTML encoding, potentially danger characters & (< > “ ; /)  in the server side, i am using encodeURI() and escape() in jsp page to encode on client side and i used URLEncoder.encode() in my java file to handel server side but it not encoding.

Comment: Sanitize what? This question is seriously lacking context. Example(s)?

Answer (score 1):

```
String needsEncodingPart = "?!@#$%^&*() <>/\"'[]{}\"";
String baseURL = "http://url:80/test";
String encodedPart = URLEncoder.encode(needsEncodingPart,"UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
System.out.println(baseURL + "/" +  encodedPart);
```

- needs to be replaced with "%20" as URLEncoder basically works with HTML type of encoding which replaces spaces with +

2nd way is to use java.net.URI

```
URL url =  new URL("http://url:80/test/test1?!@#$%^&*() <>/\"'[]{}\"");
URI uri = null;
uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost() + ":" + url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), null);
```

uri.toString() will return encoded url. But in case of # encountered it might create some issue in encoding.

Thanks,
Gaurav